# Why does SetPrecision not apply to 0?

Tags: arbitrary-precision

Is there a rationale why `SetPrecision` works on integers except for 0?

```
SetPrecision[1,5]
```

> 1.0000

```
SetPrecision[0,5]
```

> 0

Answer (score 20):

If you have a value $x$ with an absolute uncertainty $dx$ the *precision* of $x$ is by definition:

$$\text{Precision}(x) = - \log_{10}(dx/x)$$

That is why for $x=0$ the precision is always infinity. You cannot change this by changing $dx$.

If you want to assign an absolute uncertainty to zero, you can set *accuracy*, which is defined as

$$\text{Accuracy}(x) =- \log_{10}(dx)$$

This can be done using `SetAccuracy` command:

```
SetAccuracy[0, 5]
```

> 0.*10^-5

Answer (score 11):

From [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See also [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) and [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html).